# how to visible an image in ACTION_DRAG_ENDED of dropping class in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, visibility

I use this class for `setOnDragListener` for Linear Layout.
and after `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` action, I want to show(visible) an image to users. But as I run the program, `"The App Has Been Stopped"` is shown on AVD. How can I solve it?

```
 class MyDragListenerCorrect implements View.OnDragListener {
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // play sound
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                findViewById(R.id.testPanel).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_answer);

                **findViewById(R.id.img).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**
                findViewById(R.id.img).setAnimation(anim);

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

these are errors:

```
02-20 12:11:07.965    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:11:08.195    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:11:08.930    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:11:09.195    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:11:09.765    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:11:10.030    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:11:10.500    1881-2005/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ id=23(4) createSurf  0x4002f9fc (1x1),1 flag=0, QopupWindow
02-20 12:11:10.550    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:11:10.820    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:11:57.245    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:11:57.475    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:14:06.810   5994-14444/? D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 45000 Listener= com.protogeo.moves.collector.service.CollectorService@417fcd70
02-20 12:14:09.865   5994-14444/? D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener::  Listener= com.protogeo.moves.collector.service.CollectorService@417fcd70
02-20 12:15:18.065    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 5, count 1
02-20 12:15:19.585    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 5, count 0
02-20 12:16:08.845    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:16:09.090    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:16:10.505    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:16:10.760    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:16:12.295    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:16:12.550    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:16:13.545    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:16:13.805    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:16:16.705    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 5, count 1
02-20 12:16:18.240    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 5, count 0
02-20 12:16:22.540    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 5, count 1
02-20 12:16:24.055    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 5, count 0
02-20 12:16:55.585    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:16:55.825    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:16:57.320   1884-16020/? I/MFC_DEC_APP﹕ [SsbSipMfcDecOpen] MFC Library Ver 1.00
02-20 12:16:57.510   1884-15994/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 3, count 1
02-20 12:17:02.550    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:17:02.815    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:17:03.085    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 3, count 0
02-20 12:17:04.650    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:17:04.905    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:17:11.190    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:17:11.435    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:17:11.700    1881-2005/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ id=34(7) createSurf 0x4164fc8c (1280x752),1 flag=400, IomeActivit
02-20 12:18:58.215   1884-16874/? I/MFC_DEC_APP﹕ [SsbSipMfcDecOpen] MFC Library Ver 1.00
02-20 12:18:58.425   1884-16883/? I/MFC_DEC_APP﹕ [SsbSipMfcDecOpen] MFC Library Ver 1.00
02-20 12:21:58.440    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:21:58.445    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:21:58.450    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:21:58.450    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:21:58.595    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:21:58.600    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:21:59.565    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:22:00.340    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ get_native_camera: context=0x64fcc550, camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:22:00.425    2239-2606/? V/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp﹕ native_release: context=0x64fcc550 camera=0x6a589988
02-20 12:24:17.685  17680-17680/? D/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ Process (dash) fc: '/data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_cmiyc/0C66B38F48468E96F8008B6D5A2AE33B4A60265E02'
02-20 12:24:17.745  17680-17680/? V/DexLibLoader﹕ Secondary program dex metadata: secondary-3.dex.jar.xz 8f9b957d2690d1408bdfc80898712709a4e17922 secondary.dex03.Canary
02-20 12:24:17.770  17680-17680/? V/DexLibLoader﹕ Preparing to extract secondary-3.dex.jar.xz to /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_secondary_program_dex/program-8f9b957d2690d1408bdfc80898712709a4e179227b5143b.dex.jar
02-20 12:24:35.325    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:24:35.570    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:27:26.420   1884-18335/? I/MFC_DEC_APP﹕ [SsbSipMfcDecOpen] MFC Library Ver 1.00
02-20 12:27:26.640   1884-18345/? I/MFC_DEC_APP﹕ [SsbSipMfcDecOpen] MFC Library Ver 1.00
02-20 12:32:21.670   1884-18776/? I/MFC_DEC_APP﹕ [SsbSipMfcDecOpen] MFC Library Ver 1.00
02-20 12:32:21.940   1884-18785/? I/MFC_DEC_APP﹕ [SsbSipMfcDecOpen] MFC Library Ver 1.00
02-20 12:46:22.975   3212-20762/? D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 0 Listener= com.google.android.location.collectionlib.cf@41783fc8
02-20 12:46:23.445   3212-20762/? D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener::  Listener= com.google.android.location.collectionlib.cf@41783fc8
02-20 12:51:09.240    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:51:09.485    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:51:09.910    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:51:10.180    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:51:11.305   2868-21488/? D/widget﹕ [MSC_HERO_Accu_Tab]>>> WCE:267 [0:0]  FCE type = 1
02-20 12:51:11.315   2868-21489/? D/widget﹕ [MSC_HERO_Accu_Tab]>>> WCE:267 [0:0]  FCE type = 2
02-20 12:51:16.435   2868-21771/? D/widget﹕ [MSC_HERO_Accu_Tab]>>> WCE:267 [0:0]  FCE type = 1
02-20 12:51:16.435   2868-21772/? D/widget﹕ [MSC_HERO_Accu_Tab]>>> WCE:267 [0:0]  FCE type = 2
02-20 12:51:22.480    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:51:22.715    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:51:23.020    2239-2836/? D/MotionRecognitionService﹕ .registerCallback : 1, motion_sensors=3, client=com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings$5@416f8fc8
02-20 12:51:23.035    2916-2916/? V/MotionRecognitionManager﹕ .registerListener : success. listener count = 0->1, motion_sensors=2, listener=com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings$5@416f8fc8
02-20 12:51:23.125    1881-2005/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ id=58(3) createSurf 0x4116fc44 (1x1),1 flag=400, Tettings
02-20 12:51:30.065    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:51:30.120    2916-2916/? D/MotionRecognitionManager﹕ @ member 0 = com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings$5@416f8fc8
02-20 12:51:30.125    2239-3878/? D/MotionRecognitionService﹕ .unregisterCallback : 0, client=com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings$5@416f8fc8
02-20 12:51:30.130    2916-2916/? I/MotionRecognitionManager﹕ .unregisterListener : / listener count = 1->0, listener=com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings$5@416f8fc8
02-20 12:51:30.295    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:51:45.355    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:51:45.585    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:51:56.505    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:51:56.735    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:52:47.900    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:52:48.130    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:52:51.100    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:52:51.360    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:52:53.165    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:52:53.425    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:01.230    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:01.460    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:03.245    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:03.505    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:46.420    1884-2157/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:46.655    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:46.925  25423-25423/? V/NFC﹕ this device does not have NFC support
02-20 12:54:47.740    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:48.000    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:48.140    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:48.390    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:48.415    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:48.670    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:48.815    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:49.060    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 2
02-20 12:54:49.065    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:49.245    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 2
02-20 12:54:49.320    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
02-20 12:54:49.505    1884-2177/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
02-20 12:54:52.600  25423-25698/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Cache value 0x5e1efce0 deleted, size = 112
02-20 12:54:52.630  25423-25698/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Cache value 0x5e20fcb0 deleted, size = 112
02-20 12:54:52.950  25423-25698/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Cache value 0x40005fc8 deleted, size = 112
02-20 12:54:52.955  25423-25698/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Cache value 0x5ed47fc0 deleted, size = 112
02-20 12:54:52.960  25423-25698/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Cache value 0x5ed61fc8 deleted, size = 112
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Is this your complete logcat? :-O

Comment: excuse me , would you please guide me how can I LogCat in intelij? I use "fc" during running part. is it correct?

Comment: these are something that shows in Debug tab, in running.is it enough? please help me,i am starter in Android!

Comment: Don't post us the "Debug" tab. Post what you see in "Android" tab and inside "Logcat" (the tab at left with Android's green icon).

Comment: there is "Log Level" and inside it, there are "Verbose" , "Debug" , "info" , "Warn" , "Error" and "Assert" tabs.i don't have "Android" tab.

Comment: That's right. Set "log level" to "verbose" and update your question with the new logcat.

Comment: ezcuse me because of delay. there is problem in updating the post. so I copy all logCat s into txt file and upload it in "http://s4.picofile.com/file/8172017500/logCats.txt.html". in this page you will see a dark-red button and its title is "دریافت لینک دانلود" . please download it.thanks!

Comment: and also, this is another download link "http://www.4shared.com/office/fi3RbPZ_ce/logCats.html"

Comment: Have you narrowed down the crash to some specific code snippet? You said that as you launch/run the app, it crashes. I don't think launching would run `View.OnDragListener`. And what does this line do ` **findViewById(R.id.img).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**`. Seems like you wanted to comment it out?

Comment: the whole process in this activity is that,after Draging I want to change Drop's Background and also visible an Image(R.id.img) with specific animation. after app's Running, as soon as Draging-finished, the "app has been stopped" is shown.

Comment: yesterday, I found that, with typing "fc", all defected-Logs are shown. I use it and update my post. I hope its usefull!